# Magento breadcrumbs disappear on product page

Tags: php, magento, templates

I have a heavily modified magento template (not by me) that I'm having issues with.

Some products in a category when clicked on don't resolve any breadcrumbs on the product view; but others do.

I dont know where to start. Is there a snippet of code that I can check exists in the category list?

The breadcrumbs are showing but not all are listed:

```
Home>Product
```

when it should be:

```
Home>Category>subcategory>subcategory>Product.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all products are using the same product template, or if there are different templates in use.

Aslo check if in the catalog.xml the breadcrumbs have been removed or if there is a layout.xml removing those from the page.

Also check if there are any points in the phtml template where the breadcrumbs are being called and if they are not in an if clause or so

That would be the points I would be checking.  I hope that helps